# SQL: Show only those variables which contains a minus (-)

Tags: mysql

I've about 1170 records with 7 variables var1, var2, .... var7 and all these vars containing a + or -.
The following is what I want: Return only those vars per row which contains -

i.e. row 2 : VAR2 and VAR4 contains a - 
Show id row 2 and VAR2 and VAR4

i.e. row 4 : VAR1, VAR5 and VAR6 contains a - 
Show id row 4 and VAR1, VAR5 and VAR6

Comment: What is wrong with the SQL you have already written?

Comment: I didn't get any results that came near and I did it with trial and error.

Comment: Show what you tried, then; someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: SELECT VAR1, VAR2, VAR3
FROM dola
WHERE INSTR(  '-', VAR1) <>0
OR INSTR(  '-', VAR2 ) <>0
OR INSTR(  '-', VAR3 ) <>0
but this show all VARs even those with a +

Comment: Your query says to show all 3 variables for any record where any one of the variables is a -.

Comment: Okay and how to show the VARs which contains a -

Answer (score 1):

Every row returned by an SQL query has the same columns, so you can't pick and choose which to show.  But you could have the ones w/o a `-` appear blank:

```
SELECT substr(VAR1,0,instr(VAR1,'-')*10000) as VAR1_NEG FROM dola;
```

The idea here is that, if there is a `-` in VAR1, the length of the substring will be large enough to include all of VAR1; if not, the length of the substring will be 0.